# Question about cardinals.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I have heard that $2^{\omega_1} = \omega_1^{\omega_1}$. Is that true? Why is that? I have tried to find a bijection between the set of all subsets of $\omega_1$ and the set of all functions $\alpha: \omega_1 \rightarrow \omega_1$ but I haven't found it. I have also tried to prove it with the definition with no success. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you ;)

Comment: I think this question was asked like three times by now.

Comment: Whatever questions you might have about *cardinals*, I'm not sure if this site is the appropriate place to ask them. Perhaps a Catholic forum would be better ? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: $\omega_1^{\omega_1} \le (2^{\omega_1})^{\omega_1}$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have enough with that! Easier than it seemed...